# Is this single-hung sash removable?

Tags: windows

I'm getting around to long-overdue maintenance on my windows, and everything I see online suggests that this single-hung window should have tilt latches or clips, or *something* that will let me remove the sash, but I can't find anything on the window that looks obvious. To me, it looks like the frame of the sash can't physically get past the track. But I'm hoping someone knows something I don't. Can this sash be removed?

If it helps, the home was built by Lennar in 2001.

[image: Guide rod]

[image: No latch]

[image: No catch]

Answer (score 1):

The second picture, looking down at the top of the sash seems to show that there is a fixed metal piece locking the sash into the track. A picture looking up at the same part (showing the underside of what we see in that image) would likely confirm that there is no mechanism to release the sash.

While tilt-to-remove sashes have become very common over the last 20-30 years (maybe longer?), they are, by no means, *required*, so it's entirely possible that yours are not removable.